# SharePoint 2010 Custom Pages (SharePoint Foundation)

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

**I am not looking for the answer - just resources to point me in the right direction**

I have been working through some excerices and one of them I came across states:

> Instead of using the native page provided for creating and editing new
>   Member Record items, a custom page must be developed. This page will
>   created using InfoPath or VisualStudio (not SharePoint Designer), and
>   should provide separate fields for entering the First Name and Last
>   Name values, which will then be concatenated to a single value in the
>   form “LastName, FirstName” and passed to the SharePoint List when the
>   save is executed. When editing the record, the name must be again
>   split into its constituent components and put into the separate
>   fields.

I am planning to do this in VS and I have created my custom lists and all of that. The problem is, as well know, when editing or creating new entries to a list all the values are done on default pages.

Are their any resources to do what the "exercise is asking for, or any thing similar to what its asking for or has any one done anything like this and can give me some kind of direction?

**Sharepoint foundation 2010, VS2010 are being used.**

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the requirement is to create addform.aspx and editform.aspx. Have you already created it?